# SQL Script Running Total On Each Record

Tags: sql, sybase

I am writing a sql script that has following requirements:-
1) It should be able to get every record from Asset_Transaction table and for every asset calculate "Running Total" On Each Record for number of units. This running total column is calculated, by summing up the Units for all Asset_Transactions where the Transaction_datetime is less than or equal to the Transaction_datetime of the Asset_id being displayed. I have achieved that, and i think it is working ok.

However my second Requirement is:-

2) Calculate the Value of Units on that date, which is get the sell_unitPrice from Unit_Price table for the date on each asset_transaction and for that particular asset and multiply it with number of units ("Running Total") which were added . 
I am Struggling on Step 2

:---------------------------------------

### Please see the code i have written so far. Many Thanks

```
   set nocount on

   go



     declare mla_exceptions scroll cursor for
                 select distinct mla.asset_id  
from    asset_transaction mla
go



Print 'asset_id, Amount, Transaction Name, Total Units, Transaction Datetime'




declare @ml_asset double precision

open mla_exceptions



fetch first mla_exceptions


              into @ml_asset  

              while (@@sqlstatus = 0)

              begin  
              select    mla.asset_id , ',',
               -- mla.transaction_datetime, ',',
              mla.amount, ',',
              tt.name, ',',
             (select sum (units) from asset_transaction where transaction_datetime <= mla.transaction_datetime  and asset_id = @ml_asset  and status = 'A' ) 'Running Total Units', ',',
              transaction_datetime


from    asset_transaction mla noholdlock


Left outer join transaction_type tt on tt.transaction_type_id = mla.transaction_type_id
  where   mla.asset_id = @ml_asset


  order by mla.asset_id

  fetch next mla_exceptions
 into @ml_asset 
end

close mla_exceptions

deallocate cursor mla_exceptions

go
```

=========================
Many Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?  (I would guess MSSQL, but you should be explicit.)  Do you need to use a cursor?  You can do the running total as a single query.

Comment: Could you also post your database schema please?

Comment: General rule of thumb is, if you are using a cursor you are probably doing it wrong. Always try to consider set based methods first in sql as they usually perform better

Comment: Hello, Many Thanks for your replies. I am Using a Sybase Database. I don't need to use a cursor.

Comment: @MichelZ                Database Schema                  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/220/schemai.png/

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't need to use a cursor, but i don't see any other way of doing it, please see the schema above.

Comment: @ChadHenderson I am using a Syabase Database.  Many Thanks